# Blazor Server "Attempting to reconnect" issue

Tags: server, blazor, reconnect

There are a number of submissions around this question but I am yet to find a solution for my situation. Some folks report that they lose connection after minutes. "Pure luxury". I am lucky if my Blazor server circuit connection remains in place for 15 seconds. This means the awesomeness of Blazor becomes a user nightmare.

Does anyone know how to improve this situation? If not then Blazor becomes a non-starter unfortunately!

Thanks in advance